# onReceive - never called in sms app

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-pendingintent

I declared my `BroadcastReceiver` in `mainfest.xml` but `onReceive()` method is never called. What's wrong? I don't want to use register/unregister method.

**Activity:**

```
Intent sentI = new Intent("SMS_SENT");
PendingIntent sentPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sentI, 0);
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message.toString(), sentPi, null);
```

**SmsSentReceiver:**

```
 public class SmsSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     switch (getResultCode()) {
         case Activity.RESULT_OK:
             Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "SMS sent");
             break;
         case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
             Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "Generic failure");
             break;
         case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
             Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "No service");
             break;
         case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
             Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "Null PDU");
             break;
         case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
             Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "Radio off");
             break;
      }
   }   
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />


<receiver android:name="com.mateusz.simplesmsapp.broadcasts.SmsSentReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: try adding <category android:name="your packagename" /> within intent filter

Comment: Set its priority to 999... its maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've registered the Receiver in the manifest for this action: `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"`. However, the Intent you're creating for the broadcast is using this action: `"SMS_SENT"`. These need to match.